# Careers 2.0 cannot retrieve URL of blog post I wrote

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I tried to add an article I wrote to my profile but I receive an error response of:
"Sorry, we could not retrieve that URL for some reason."

I have been able to add links from 2 other domains, so I am not sure if there is some issue with the host of this blog post. The link I am using is:
https://career.eng.ohio-state.edu/blog/?p=843

Comment: I'm also getting an [SSL error](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=career.eng.ohio-state.edu) on that site, which is also a problem.

Answer (score 7):

We do a HEAD request to the URL to see what type of content it is, followed by a GET if it’s HTML. In this case, the server is returning a 403 Forbidden on the HEAD request, at which point we stop.

(I also tried doing manual raw HTTP HEAD requests with the same result.)

Comment: You mean people actually use HEAD requests?

Comment: Heh, yes. In this case, we want to know if it’s HTML before GETting the payload. If it’s not HTML (eg PDF), we don’t want the payload, just the URL.