# Can't add a project or article specified by URL to profile

Tags: support, jobs

I tried adding a project and article that I host on my web server to my profile but both attempts fail with a "Sorry, we could not retrieve that URL for some reason" error message. Checking the web server logs there doesn't seem to have been any attempt to connect to the web server. The URL is http://www.csclub.uwaterloo.ca:11068/mymc/ and I suspect the fact that I'm using a non-standard HTTP port isn't helping.

Comment: This might explain what happens: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132026/careers-2-0-cannot-retrieve-url-of-blog-post-i-wrote

Comment: Apparently they switched back to using `GET` a couple of years ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/154887/266854 Either way I don't see any `GET` or `HEAD` requests in the web server logs.

Comment: Weird, guess we'll have to wait for a dev then. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is correct - we only allow outgoing connections from our web servers over ports 80 or 443. This means you can't add a URL that uses a non-standard port, as we won't be able to retrieve it.

Comment: Why not give more meaningful error then e.g. "We do not support this port"?

Comment: For the usual reason that it's a "nice to have" feature. We would have to explicitly code this, as the block happens in the firewall. The Careers app simply tries to send a request to that URL and finds it can't connect.